# How to calculate the day of the week based on unix time

Tags: date, math

I know that there are functions/classes in most programming languages to do that, but I would like to know the calculation.

So: How do I get from the unix time in seconds to a day-number (e.g. 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday etc.)?

Thanks in advance. BTW: this is my first post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem you ask is reasonably easy, compared to how ridiculously complicated other date/time functions can be (e.g. [Zeller's congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence)).

0. Unix time is defined as the number of seconds elapsed after January 1, 1970, at 00:00 (midnight) UTC.
1. You can look up a calendar to find that 1970-01-01 was a Thursday. There are 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400 seconds in a day.
2. Therefore values 0 to 86399 are Thursday, 86400 to 172799 are Friday, 172800 to 259199 are Saturday, etc. These are blocks of 86400 seconds aligned at 0.
3. **Suppose *T* is your Unix timestamp.** Then floor(*T* / 86400) tells you the number of days after 1970-01-01. 0 = Thursday January 1st; 1 = Friday January 2nd; 2 = Saturday January 3rd; etc.
4. Add 4 and modulo 7. Now 0 → 4; 1 → 5; 2 → 6; 3 → 0; 4 → 1; 5 → 2; 6 → 3; 7 → 4; 8 → 5; 9 → 6; 10 → 0; etc. This is your final answer.
5. **In summary: day of week = (floor(*T* / 86400) + 4) mod 7.**
6. (This assumes that you want the day of week in UTC. If you want to calculate it for another time zone, you need to perform some addition or subtraction of hours and minutes on *T* first.)

Comment: @wberry: Your edit leaves "0 → 4; 1 → 5; 2 → 6; 3 → 0; 4 → 1; 5 → 2; 6 → 3; 7 → 4; 8 → 5; 9 → 6; 10 → 0" - which doesn't make sense. Additionally, it looks to me like it really *should* be adding 4, assuming that the original post is correct about Jan 1st 1970 being a Thursday. (Note that in the question, Thursday should have a numeric value of 4. That may not be *your* situation, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for checking and defending my answer!

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, days of the week are:

```
0 = Sun
1 = Mon
2 = Tue
3 = Wed
4 = Thu
5 = Fri
6 = Sat
```

You can use built-in methods:

```
// Unix epoch, 4 = Thu
new Date(0).getUTCDay()

// Today, 2 = Tue
new Date().getUTCDay()
```

Or a custom solution (remember to divide getTime() milliseconds  by 1000):

```
// Unix epoch, 4 = Thu
(Math.floor(new Date(0).getTime() / 86400 / 1000) + 4) % 7

// Today, 2 = Tue
(Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 86400 / 1000) + 4) % 7
```

Solution (from Geek for Geeks):

```
function dayofweek(d, m, y) {
  let t = [ 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 ];
  y -= (m < 3) ? 1 : 0;
  return ( y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
}

// Unix epoch, 4 = Thu
Math.round(dayofweek(1, 1, 1970))

// Today, 2 = Tue
Math.round(dayofweek(7, 12, 2021))
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date/

Comment: The algorithm you lifted from GeeksforGeeks is wrong. All the divisions need to be floored immediately, not summed up and then floored. For example, your `dayOfWeek(1, 4, 1943)` = 5.1775000000002365, but the correct answer is 4.

Comment: Geek for geek updated their example. Have updated here to match.